# Square::getArea()too hard

Tags: c++

I want to get the output of the area up to the second decimal place.
For example, output : width=2 height=33 area=66.00
But output of this code is width=2 height=33 area=66

```
double Square::getArea(){
    return width * height;
}
void Square::print(){
    cout << " : width=" << (int)width << " height=" << (int)height << " area=" << Square::getArea();
}
```

Comment: You should have a look onto [Input/output manipulators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip). [`std::setprecision`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setprecision) could be what you need.

Comment: (Shouldn't width equal height with `Square`s? `width * height` looks parallelogram.)

Answer (score 1):

The use of the following statement should definitely solve your problem `std::setprecision(number of digits)`